# How do I calculate the Fourier sine coefficient for this function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a function u(t) which is 0 for $ -\frac{\pi}{\omega} < t < 0 $ and $ Esin(\omega t)$ for $0 < t < \frac{\pi}{\omega}$. I calculated $a_0$ and $a_n$, but when I try to calculate $b_n = \frac{\omega E}{\pi} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{\omega} sin(\omega t)sin(n \omega t)dt$, I get the following expression which I don't know how to evaluate for $n=1$, and which is 0 for $n > 1$: $b_n = \frac{E}{2 \pi}(\frac{sin((1-n)\pi)}{1-n} - \frac{sin((1+n)\pi}{n+1})$

The answer is supposed to be $b_1 = \frac{E}{2}$. Could someone please explain how I can find this?

Comment: use the taylorexpansion of $\sin$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula
$$
b_n=\frac{E}{2\pi}\Bigl(\frac{\sin((1-n)\pi)}{1-n}-\frac{\sin((1+n)\pi)}{1+n}\Bigr)
$$
is *not* valid for $n=1$, since then you divide by zero.

To calculate the coefficient $b_1$, you could reduce the integrand to
$$
\sin^2(\omega t)=\frac{1-\cos(2\omega t)}{2},
$$
which you probably know how to integrate?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I should set n=1 before evaluating the integral? That is also how my textbook does it, but do you know if there is any other way?

Comment: I don't see why one would need another method. Here, you could also take the limit of your expression of $b_n$ as $n\to 1$. By invoking $\sin x/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$, you will get $E/2$.